# Run a new task under the Airflow DAG which is already succeeded

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I've added a new task under the existing DAG and since its deployment onwards (say, 2022-03-08), it is running fine.

However, I also want to run this task for days before its deployed date. Say I want to run a task from 2022-03-01 till 2022-03-07 (Because - I have to load previous data) and the existing already finished successfully for those dates.

How could I achieve that? Instead of manually running the newly added tasks for those dates.

In the below picture, we can see that the new task is running fine from its deployed date but how would I trigger it for the previous dates? At least dates for which I have the data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution:

1. If you need to backfill then choose date from base date field. [image]
2. click on Go button
3. Click on newly added task
4. Clear the task with downstream and future selection [image]

Note: this will clear all future downstream task

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be not a perfect one but at least it works:

1. I am marking the step as failed
2. And after just clear it

Note: second step could be easily done in bulk *HOST/taskinstance/list* page

Comment: How you are going to mark that task as failed? Because if you click on that task for any day and select mark failed, it will not mark that task a failure and neither marking success will work.

Comment: Just click and mark failed works for me. Version: v2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

My Solution - Created a separate DAG with only those tasks that were newly added and provided start_data and end_date in the DAG initialization. This separate DAG helped in loading the data.
I performed this on Airflow version - 1.10.10